# How to resolve NuGet Assemblies on external Program

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget

I have the following problem:
We develop as team a software, that is made up of multiple console applications (netcoreapp2.1) and libraries (netstandard2.0). And we also have a Version Control.

The console application is a stand-alone sulution. When i start it from Visual Studio, it loads the external assemblies from "..\modules" and all NuGet packages from C:\Users[Username].nuget\packages or C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder

When i now want to debug the library, i set in "Visual Studio -> Project properties -> Debug" to start external program and point to the "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" and set as parameters the path of the console application. But when i start this, it doesn't resolve any NuGet Package.

I tried a AssemblyResolver, that finds the correct NuGet Package, but there are many problems to find the correct assembly and also some perfomance issues.
Another possible solution is to copy all the assemblies to bin\Debug folder. But i don't want to check it in into the repository. But without, the next team member has the same problems to start the project.

So how can i solve this problem? Maybee any start parameter for dotnet?

Thanks so far...

Comment: "The console application is a stand-alone sulution." Why?

Comment: Because we have different customer projects with special bussiness logic. But the console applications are non-project related. Thats why they read the assemblies via MEF.